# How can I generate big data sample for Postgresql using generate_series and random?

Tags: postgresql

I want to generate big data sample (almost 1 million records) for studying tuplesort.c's polyphase merge in postgresql, and I hope the schema as follows:

```
CREATE TABLE Departments (code VARCHAR(4), UNIQUE (code));
CREATE TABLE Towns (
  id SERIAL UNIQUE NOT NULL,
  code VARCHAR(10) NOT NULL, -- not unique
  article TEXT,
  name TEXT NOT NULL, -- not unique
  department VARCHAR(4) NOT NULL REFERENCES Departments (code),
  UNIQUE (code, department)
);
```

how to use generate_series and random for do it? thanks a lot!

Answer (score 132, accepted):

To insert one million rows into `Towns`

```
insert into towns (
    code, article, name, department
)
select
    left(md5(i::text), 10),
    md5(random()::text),
    md5(random()::text),
    left(md5(random()::text), 4)
from generate_series(1, 1000000) s(i)
```

Since `id` is a `serial` it is not necessary to include it.

### Reference

**left ( string text, n integer ) → text**

- Returns first n characters in the string, or when n is negative, returns all but last |n| characters.
- `left('abcde', 2)` → ab

**md5 ( text ) → text**

- Computes the MD5 hash of the argument, with the result written in hexadecimal.
- `md5('abc')` → 900150983cd24fb0​d6963f7d28e17f72

**generate_series ( start integer, stop integer [, step integer ] ) → setof integer**

Generates a series of values from start to stop, with a step size of step. step defaults to 1.

Refs

- [set functions](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/16/functions-srf.html)
- [text functions](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/functions-string.html#id-1.5.8.10.7.2.2.8.1.1.1)

Comment: thank you! this function is great! and, **md5()** and **left()** are functions postgresql provided?

Comment: @abelard20008 Yes native postgresql functions

Comment: I attempted to make this match the OP's tables a bit more, but seem to still run into a hash collision, any advice?

Comment: what is `s(i)`?

Comment: `s(i)` is a table and column alias. It's telling the query to treat the data from the `generate_series` function as a table named `s` with a column named `i`. You can see this by replacing `i::text` with the equivalent `s.i::text` in the statement above. See this [documentation](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/queries-table-expressions.html#QUERIES-TABLE-ALIASES) for more information.