# Generate random elements in PostgreSQL

Tags: sql, postgresql

I have some problem.

I have a small table below:

```
CREATE TABLE person (
    person_id SERIAL PRIMARY KEY,
    first_name TEXT NOT NULL,
    last_name TEXT NOT NULL,
    patronymic TEXT,
    birth_date TIMESTAMP,
    photo_id INTEGER UNIQUE
);
```

I need to check how some my screepts work with lots of data. So I need to generate a lot of random data **with PostgreSQL tools**. Like

```
INSERT INTO MY_TABLE(id,name,...)
SELECT id, md5(random()::text)
FROM generate_series(1,100) id;
```

But how can I do it whith TIMESTAMP and INTEGER UNIC?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How can I generate big data sample for Postgresql using generate\_series and random?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24841142/how-can-i-generate-big-data-sample-for-postgresql-using-generate-series-and-rand)

Answer (score 2):

For example:

```sql
INSERT INTO person (id, name, ..., birth_date, photo_id)
SELECT g AS id
     , md5(random()::text) AS name
     , ...
     , LOCALTIMESTAMP - interval '100 years' * random() AS birth_date
     , g + 12345 AS photo_id    -- also UNIQUE
FROM   generate_series(1,100) g;
```

Why `timestamp` and not `date` for `"birth_date"`?

Answer (score 1):

To generate random alien names, birth dates, photo id's

> ```
> CREATE TABLE person (
>     person_id SERIAL PRIMARY KEY,
>     first_name TEXT NOT NULL,
>     last_name TEXT NOT NULL,
>     patronymic TEXT,
>     birth_date DATE,
>     photo_id INTEGER UNIQUE
> );
> ```

> ```
> CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION base26_encode(IN digits bigint, IN min_width int = 0)
>   RETURNS varchar AS $$
>         DECLARE
>           chars char[];
>           ret varchar;
>           val bigint;
>       BEGIN
>       chars := ARRAY['A','B','C','D','E','F','G','H','I','J','K','L','M'
>                     ,'N','O','P','Q','R','S','T','U','V','W','X','Y','Z'];
>       val := digits;
>       ret := '';
>       IF val < 0 THEN
>           val := val * -1;
>       END IF;
>       WHILE val != 0 LOOP
>           ret := chars[(val % 26)+1] || ret;
>           val := val / 26;
>       END LOOP;
>
>       IF min_width > 0 AND char_length(ret) < min_width THEN
>           ret := lpad(ret, min_width, '0');
>       END IF;
>
>       RETURN ret;
>  
> END;
> $$ LANGUAGE 'plpgsql' IMMUTABLE;
> ```

> ```
> INSERT INTO person (
>  first_name, 
>  last_name, 
>  patronymic, 
>  birth_date, 
>  photo_id
> )
> SELECT 
>   initcap(base26_encode(substring(random()::text,3,10)::bigint)) as first_name
> , initcap(base26_encode(substring(random()::text,3,15)::bigint)) as last_name
> , initcap(base26_encode(substring(random()::text,3,9)::bigint)) as patronymic
> , 'now'::date - (interval '90 years' * random()) AS birth_date
> , ceil(random()*2100000000) as photo_id
> FROM generate_series(1,10) num;
> ```

> ```
> select *
> from person
> order by person_id
> ```

| person_id | first_name | last_name | patronymic | birth_date | photo_id |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | Cgdmyty | Bvmvzwflixr | Bxqseru | 1975-04-30 | 735546878 |
| 2 | Fnvbyvm | Gfcfcfqmqzf | Dddevru | 1994-08-05 | 1001397097 |
| 3 | Bcwpzckn | Dbotgnxawv | Ntvguj | 1978-04-23 | 2061692939 |
| 4 | Otxeaqq | Gsordusztt | Bydwdyn | 2006-06-07 | 1237488926 |
| 5 | Yvgsydx | Bsctpuizkfu | Dljgzg | 1996-06-14 | 513060685 |
| 6 | Bekfepnq | Nurheomrkd | Cesnzqr | 1937-04-02 | 821299133 |
| 7 | Tmofbgf | Cakqaxqkhw | Ccqdiav | 2004-10-10 | 1112427504 |
| 8 | Bgjaallw | Couazhvqmvp | Biavado | 1935-05-05 | 1401285419 |
| 9 | Bcnrcurk | Gblvvxkxbel | Csduzpr | 2017-12-31 | 715217821 |
| 10 | Bakcxfzn | Jfvmbyvawt | Bftbpyz | 1985-01-12 | 1415422286 |

*db<>fiddle [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_10&fiddle=ec9395dd54d825eb88a5851f16f3ccd3)*