# Inserting dummy data into Postgresql

Tags: sql, database, postgresql

I'am creating a Postgres database and now I want to insert dummy data so I can learn to use ModelBI and other analysis tools. So far I've created some tables and found an automated way to insert the data with a postgres function but I'm getting an error.

Here is my table:

```
CREATE TABLE Customers (
    ID int NOT NULL,
    Name varchar(50) NOT NULL,
    Phone varchar(15) NOT NULL,
    Address varchar(50),
    Birthday date NOT NULL,
    CustomerEmail varchar(50) NOT NULL,
    PRIMARY KEY (ID)
);
```

And here is the function that I'm using to try and generate data:

```
INSERT INTO Customers(ID, Name, Phone, Address,Birthday,CustomerEmail)
SELECT md5(random()::int), md5(random()::text), md5(random()::text)::varchar(15), md5(random()::text::varchar(50),md5(random()::date),md5(random()::text::varchar(50)  
FROM generate_series(1,100);
```

Comment: What's the error?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How can I generate big data sample for Postgresql using generate\_series and random?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24841142/how-can-i-generate-big-data-sample-for-postgresql-using-generate-series-and-rand)

Answer (score 0):

Please create customer table using below ddl .

```
CREATE TABLE Customers (
    ID  serial ,
    Name varchar(50) NOT NULL,
    Phone varchar(15) NOT NULL,
    Address varchar(50),
    Birthday date NOT NULL,
    CustomerEmail varchar(50) NOT NULL,
    PRIMARY KEY (ID)
);
```

for dynamic data generation, execute below command:

```
INSERT INTO Customers( Name, Phone, Address,Birthday,CustomerEmail)
SELECT  left(md5(random()::text),10), 
left(md5(random()::text),10), 
left(md5(random()::text),10),
(now()+ random() * '2 days':: Interval) ::DATE,
concat(left(md5(random()::text),6),'@domain.com')
FROM generate_series(1,100);
```